# How to set UITabBarItem.BadgeColor to color (from resource file)

Tags: maui, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to set the badge color of a UITabBarItem from a resource file, but will settle for anything other than the [default red](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbaritem/1648567-badgecolor).

I've created a custom `ShellTabBarAppearanceTracker` for the iOS platform, and attempting to update the badge color from via an event handler.

```
class BadgeShellTabbarAppearanceTracker : ShellTabBarAppearanceTracker
{
    private UITabBarItem? notificationTabbarItem;
    public override void UpdateLayout(UITabBarController controller)
    {
        // Set event listener to UpdateBadge here when count changes
    }

    private void UpdateBadge(int count)
    {
        if (notificationTabbarItem is not null)
        {
                Color cyan;
                if (App.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("CyanAccent", out var colorvalue))
                {
                    cyan = (Color)colorvalue;
                    notificationTabbarItem.BadgeColor = cyan.ToPlatform();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

All of the `UpdateBadge` code is being reached on every count change. It even appears to be setting the color correctly when stepping through and inspecting the variables.

[image: Watch variable result]

Replacing the lookup to the resource directory, and setting the color to a standard MAUI color doesn't change it either.

`notificationTabbarItem.BadgeColor = Colors.Blue.ToPlatform();`

I've tried invoking this on the main thread with no change:

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    item.BadgeColor = Colors.Blue.ToPlatform();
});
```

And also directly through the `TabBar.StandardAppearance`:

```
var appearance = controller.TabBar.StandardAppearance;
appearance.StackedLayoutAppearance.Normal.BadgeBackgroundColor = Colors.Pink.ToPlatform();
appearance.InlineLayoutAppearance.Normal.BadgeBackgroundColor = Colors.Pink.ToPlatform();
appearance.CompactInlineLayoutAppearance.Normal.BadgeBackgroundColor = Colors.Pink.ToPlatform();
```

Very similar code to the original snippet works perfectly for Android.

Where/how should I be setting the color of the badge?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct API to modify the Badge Color in MAUI. You could raise a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) if you want.

And yes there is a workaround but a little bit tricky. That is to use Maui Handler.

I recommend you refer to [How to Increase Font Size for TabBar Menu Items in .NET MAUI on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77826418/20118901). Our workaround for this case also uses this process.

The only difference is for **TabbedViewExtensions.cs**. (The answer link I posted above adds some code to change `UIStringAttributes`. Don't forget to delete them). Add the following line **TabbedViewExtensions.cs** to change the Badge Color,

```
    internal static void UpdateiOS15TabBarAppearance(
        this UITabBar tabBar,
        ref UITabBarAppearance _tabBarAppearance,
        UIColor? defaultBarColor,
        UIColor? defaultBarTextColor,
        Color? selectedTabColor,
        Color? unselectedTabColor,
        Color? barBackgroundColor,
        Color? selectedBarTextColor,
        Color? unSelectedBarTextColor)
    {
        ...

        //Add the following line
        if (App.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("CyanAccent", out var colorvalue))
        {
            var cyan = (Color)colorvalue;
   _tabBarAppearance.StackedLayoutAppearance.Normal.BadgeBackgroundColor = cyan.ToPlatform();

        }

       ...
```

---

Here is the effect that change badge color from red to cyan.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Massive thank you Liqun. I'll give it a go and get back to you.

Comment: Hey Liqun. This worked perfectly! Thank you for the help. . . it felt like I'd tried to override everything to get my code working. I learned a bunch reading through the example too.

Comment: Glad it helps! Because there is no direct API to change the badge color for MAUI, we have to override a lot of things. Actually, most of the code are from MAUI source. We just need to make slight modification.